# How do I sync an offline web app (HTML+JS+CSS) with my server?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, web-applications

Do I need to implement my own sync methods in order to make an offline web app (html+css+js) stay up to date with changes made on the server (and viceversa)? I'm using MySQL on the server side.

I read [Two-way sync between iPhone application and web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106191/) with some pointers but I think they're talking about native applications when they mention CFUUIDCreate and I wander if this is possible for the Web.

Does someone have some code to share or maybe can point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

P.S.: I hope my english is not that rusty ;)

Answer (score 2):

**To store static contents on the client-side**, as Jethro Larson said, the Application Cache Manifest is the way to go to cache the static contents of your website (HTML, CSS, JS and images).

**To handle dynamically generated contents offline**, you can use javascript templates. There are [several solutions](http://microjs.com/#templating) for this.

**To sync the two databases**, there is a project called persistence.js (*persistencejs.org*) which is a javascript library which offers a unique API to work with WebSQL databases, Local Storage, etc. They have a plugin for this library called persistence.sync (*persistencejs.org/plugin/sync*) which syncs the remote database with the server's one. It consists of POST and GET requests to a specific url that you can configure (for example yourapp.dev/sync). They have an example back-end written in node.js and [here is one for Rails](https://github.com/dmfrancisco/Desligado/blob/master/app/controllers/items_controller.rb). It's simple to understand and persistence.sync is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the offline cache:
http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Application-Caching/
http://www.google.com/search?q=offline+cache+html5
http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?q=offline+cache

Comment: Thanks but I've read about this stuff and it covers cache and so but I'm still in doubt about how to proceed with database synchronization.

Comment: Your request is vague, I don't know how to respond. Any sync will be over http. There's no magic tricks. I know there's html5 databases as well but I'm not sure if that'll help you.

Comment: It's not easy. I think in spanish. Not the best way, I know. I'm just looking for some help trying to understand how to write an implementation to sync two databases, one HTML5 client-side database and one MySQL database accessed by PHP. Using an UUID? Maybe using auto incremented IDs in both sides and timestamps everywhere? Are there any standards related to this? ... Are JSON or XML an option to move this data? Can I move it through a web socket)?

Comment: Oh. I see. I doubt there's a standard solution for this yet. client-side databases are really new. I would never treat server-side and client-side databases as the same due to the security vulnerabilities. As for data exchange you could use AJAX requests to send/receive data. Web sockets would work but I'm not sure what the advantage would be. And remember that these specs are new and not well supported cross-browser.